# Problem with determining the right HSV range

Tags: c++, opencv

Using a similar code mentioned here, I detected the red ball like this:
[image]

**Lower: [0,0,0] Upper[14, 211, 131]** (I also tried 1-2 step more-less than this range)

Now I want to detect this red ball from a live capture. So wrote:

```
   cv::medianBlur(image,image,3);

   // Convert input image to HSV
   cv::Mat hsv_image;
   cv::cvtColor(image, hsv_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

   cv::Mat red_hue_image;
   cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(14, 211, 131), red_hue_image);
```

But it did not work.
I did exactly the same thing on a yellow ball with this range:
**Lower:[15, 162, 0] , Upper[180, 255, 255]**

With this code:

```
   cv::medianBlur(image,image,3);

    // Convert input image to HSV
   cv::Mat hsv_image;
   cv::cvtColor(image, hsv_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

   cv::Mat yellow_hue_image;
   cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(15, 162, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255), yellow_hue_image);
```

And it worked well for the yellow ball. How to do that on the red one too, what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: If the detection is based on the color, shouldn't the `value` range be always between `0` and `255`? Or at least with some cutoff at the lower boundary, to get rid off some noisy values. Firstly, I'd try to perform detection based only on the `hue` range and ignore both saturation and value.

Comment: Use `Upper[14, 255, 255]` to ignore brightness and saturation for now.

Comment: Use two range for red color: (0,0,0)-(14,255,255) and (bitwise and) (165,0,0)-(179,255,255).

Comment: If your Hue range is near to red and it wraps around from 170 through 0 to 14, you can invert your image and look for cyan where it will be contiguous 